# Lisp code - how to run this example

Tags: lisp

This comes from an interview for a sysadmin position.

During the test, I discovered a cookie. It contained a message that was base64 encoded, next it was uuencoded, next was bzip, and last was gzip.
After all that decompressing, it contained the following code:

```
(let* ((x '((1 2 (3 4 5) 6) 7 8 (9 10))))
  ;; use car/caaa..r/cd..r here to get 4 from x
  )
```

I think it's Lisp. I am now trying to find out what this was supposed to do.
I have no knowledge of Lisp, so can anyone help?

Comment: I can help - yes, it's Lisp (or Scheme or Clojure).

Comment: This is question from job survey. It is not programmer job. It's for sys admin. The questing was in cookie, next i was base64 encoded, next it was uuencoded, next was bzip, and last was gzip. And I got this lisp code. I'm no programmer :( I think i did good job with reveling all this encodings but Lisp? :(

Comment: Thank you. It's ok. I'm reading Lisp tutorial right now :)

Comment: You're welcome. Meanwhile I'm wondering why this organisation would want sysadmins to know Lisp - only reason I can think of is [Emacs Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs_Lisp).

Comment: In a few days I will have the opportunity to ask them about it. But I saw  that they gave the same question for  security related job. So I think it's general question about how you deal with problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very simple (and maybe the easiest to understand) code:

```
(car (cdr (car (cdr (cdr (car x))))))
```

**(car l)** gives you the first element of the list **l**

**(cdr l)** gives you the remaining elements of the list **l** (in a list themselves)

Try out each call individually to see what is going on.

It is indeed Lisp. If you want to know a little bit more and be better prepared for future interviews you can try the [Casting Spells in Lisp](http://www.lisperati.com/casting.html) tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

```
(let* ((x '((1 2 (3 4 5) 6) 7 8 (9 10))))

 ; use car/caaa..r/cd..r here to get 4 from x

)
```

So you should write the code to access the `4` from the nested list `((1 2 (3 4 5) 6) 7 8 (9 10))`.

The Common Lisp Hyperspec gives you the available accessor functions: [Accessor CAR, CDR, ...](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_car_c.htm).

```
> (CADR (CADDAR '((1 2 (3 4 5) 6) 7 8 (9 10))))
4
```

So the code is:

```
(let* ((x '((1 2 (3 4 5) 6) 7 8 (9 10))))
   (cadr (caddar x)))
```